# Subset of a vector space

Tags: linear-algebra

Consider the vector space $V=\mathbb{R}^{2}$. Find a set which satisfies the properties, or show that no such set exists.

A set which contains the zero vector which is not closed under addition and not closed under scalar multiplication.

I really can't think of a set so I am starting to think no such set exists but I also don't really know how to show no such set exists. Can anyone give me some hints?

Comment: Consider any finite set containing the zero vector and at least one other vector.

Comment: Ah of course, I was trying to make a more general case but this is certainly easier

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Any set of the form 
$$
\{ v \in \mathbb{R}^2 : |v| < n \}
$$